# print numbers from 200 to 150 in reverse order and print numbers from 200 to 150 in a sequential order using while?

Tags: java

how to print numbers from 200 to 150 in reverse order and print numbers from 200 to 150 in a sequential order using single while loop?

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        while(n>=150) {
            System.out.println(n);
            n--;
        }  
        n=0;
        while(n<=150) {
            System.out.println(n);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use a `while` loop? `IntStream.rangeClosed(150, 200).forEachOrdered(i -> System.out.printf("%d %d%n", i, 150 + (200 - i)));`

Comment: quite easy. in one print, you have x, in the other you have 200-x. but first try to write code that 'll compile

Answer (score -1):

Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 150;
    while(n <= 200) {
        System.out.println("Decreasing : " + (150 + (200 - n)));
        System.out.println("Increating : " + (n++));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but my guess, because you are handing out custom code, which won't learn the OP anything but to improve his/her copy-paste skills, and you didn't provide any actual comments/information to go with the code.